# Don't warn about 15 character minimum for titles until body content added

Tags: feature-request, title, character-limit

If I type a small amount of text into a title, then switch browser tabs, and then come back to the question, I get a warning about the 15 character minimum. I'm using Google Chrome and OS X.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Can we delay this warning such that it only shows once you start entering text into the body of the question?